# Why is volitional form used before ということになった (decide?)?

Tags: grammar

『……そこで、琴里のことをよく知るクルーたちを集めて、二日後のデートプランについて**話し合おうということになった**んだが、是非シンにも参加してもらいたいと思ってね』

そういうことならば是非もない。士道は大きくうなずいた。

「わかりました。役に立つかはわかりませんけど、是非協力させてください」

Context: シン is 士道 and first speaker wanted 士道 to attend the discussion so that they can help 琴里.

Hi. Does the bold ということになった mean “it’s been decided that...”? If so, why isn’t the plain form 話し合う used there? According to grammar, shouldn’t we use plain form before ということになった when the expression means “it’s been decided that...”?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ～ようということになった is the combination of the volitional form (よ)う and the ことになった construction. The difference is small, but with the volitional form, I feel the focus is put more on the *will* to do something.

- 京都に旅行に行くことになった。
  → We decided to go on a trip to Kyoto.
- 京都に旅行に行こうということになった。
  → We agreed on the will/plan to go on a trip to Kyoto (we may change our mind later while trying to make a concrete plan).

Note that this doesn't mean you always have to translate them differently.